# Proof that the length function $\ell: \operatorname{Teich}(S) \to \mathbb{R}^\mathcal{S}$ is injective without the $9g-9$ theorem

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory

In Chapter 10 about Teichmüller spaces of Farb and Margalit's "A Primer to Mapping Class Groups", the length function
$$\ell: \operatorname{Teich}(S) \to \mathbb{R}^\mathcal{S}$$
is described, where $S$ is a compact surface with finitely many punctures and $\chi(S) < 0$ and $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the set of isotopy classes of essential simple closed curves in $S$.

It is already impressive that the map $\ell$ is injective (which they also remark), however they prove the much stronger $9g-9$ theorem.

**Question:** Is there a (simpler) proof that $\ell$ is injective **without** showing that the length function is actually determined by its value on only $9g-9$ simple closed curves?

I've searched for a bit now, and came across e.g. [these](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jaramayo/currents.pdf) lecture notes, where Theorem 3.3 claims that the map is injective. The reference given is "Travaux de Thurston sur les surfaces", in which Theorem 7.9 states that $\ell$ is injective. However, it is not proven independently from the $9g-9$ theorem after all.

Comment: Your last sentence is worded strangely: Theorem 7.9 *is* proven, because it is a corollary of the $9g-9$ theorem.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, I realize that it is a corollary, what I mean is that it is not explicitly proven (even though stated) independently from the $9g-9$ theorem.

Answer (score 3):

There is a representation-theoretic viewpoint, where one can consider traces of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ representations (determined by lengths of geodesic up to sign). Then one sees that the trace variety is determined by traces of simple closed curves, modulo certain relations. See [papers of Feng Luo](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214425638), for example. He shows that the modulus of the surface is determined by the moduli of all of the 1-punctured tori and 4-punctured sphere subsurfaces. In turn, it is not hard to show that the modulus of a once punctured torus is determined by the lengths of 3 curves intersecting pairwise once (the complementary regions are two triangles with vertices on the 3 Weierstrass points, and an annulus: the triangle has sidelengths half the geodesic lengths, and then one can see that the lengths determines the geometry of the triangles and annulus; there is a similar picture for 4-punctured spheres).

See this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/243622/1345) for more references on parameterizing Teichmuller space by geodesic lengths.